# Simplest way to post to a facebook fan page's wall with C#!

Tags: c#, facebook, api, sdk

I have a fan page setup for my company.

I want to automate the posting of regular updates to that page's wall from my C# desktop application.

- Which Facebook C# library is the simplest?
- How can I easily acquire the access token for this page?
- What is the most concise code snippet that will simply allow me to then post to the wall?

I have read through all the docs and millions of stackoverflow and blog posts and it all seems very convoluted. Surely it can't be that hard..

I have setup an "application" within facebook that has its own App ID, API Key and App Secret etc.

Comment: I may be outdated, but it sounds like you're making a similar assumption to one I made when I tackled this problem; it's not any easier because you only want to access one page, that is yours (your client's). You still need to build the infrastructure (popup the facebook login, request permission, handle the redirect for the auth token), that could work for an arbitrary user, even if you only do it once, for yourself as an admin. It's not too bad, but I don't think there's an easy one liner to get it done, you need to do all the authentication.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@Aaron - the best library is the facebook c# sdk. I use it every day... granted I am biased as my company writes it - but it's a dynamic library and with the rate of updates from Facebook (every Tuesday) it is well suited for scalable development.

http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/

I won't get into authentication with it - as on codeplex there are many examples:
http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20Examples&referringTitle=Documentation
But to do a post to a page, after you have authenticated and have an access token, the code would be something like this:

```
dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
messagePost.access_token = "[YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]";
messagePost.picture = "[A_PICTURE]";
messagePost.link = "[SOME_LINK]";
messagePost.name = "[SOME_NAME]";
messagePost.caption = "{*actor*} " + "[YOUR_MESSAGE]"; //<---{*actor*} is the user (i.e.: Aaron)
messagePost.description = "[SOME_DESCRIPTION]";

FacebookClient app = new FacebookClient("[YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]");

try
{
    var result = app.Post("/" + [PAGE_ID] + "/feed", messagePost);
}
catch (FacebookOAuthException ex)
{
     //handle something
}
catch (FacebookApiException ex)
{
     //handle something else
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Joey. Turned out I did end up finding and using your library. Yeah it did look the best compared to the others and the many examples included in the download package were very helpful. I ended up modifying the "CSWinFormsAuthTool" sample project and was able to get the correct access token fairly quickly. Then with some further modifications I got the actual call down to just 2 lines of code! It works really well. Many thanks.

Comment: @AAron, "was able to get the correct access token fairly quickly" - how did you end up doing that?  thanks!

Comment: I'm getting this error while posting some message to page.(OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action. who is the "user" in this context? Can someone help me in solving this. I even added permissions before getting the access token

Comment: FacebookClient code is outdated. you can no longer simply pass in an access token it requires a clientid and secret which is useless for apps that utilize non-expiring tokens.

Answer (score 11):

I am posting this because of lack of good information on the internet that led to me spend more time than I needed.  I hope this will benefit others.  The key is adding &scope=manage_pages,offline_access,publish_stream to the url.

```
class Program
{
    private const string FacebookApiId = "apiId";
    private const string FacebookApiSecret = "secret";

    private const string AuthenticationUrlFormat =
        "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=manage_pages,offline_access,publish_stream";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string accessToken = GetAccessToken(FacebookApiId, FacebookApiSecret);

        PostMessage(accessToken, "My message");
    }

    static string GetAccessToken(string apiId, string apiSecret)
    {
        string accessToken = string.Empty;
        string url = string.Format(AuthenticationUrlFormat, apiId, apiSecret);

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

            NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(responseString);

            accessToken = query["access_token"];
        }

        if (accessToken.Trim().Length == 0)
            throw new Exception("There is no Access Token");

        return accessToken;
    }

    static void PostMessage(string accessToken, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

            dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
            messagePost.access_token = accessToken;
            //messagePost.picture = "[A_PICTURE]";
            //messagePost.link = "[SOME_LINK]";
            //messagePost.name = "[SOME_NAME]";
            //messagePost.caption = "my caption"; 
            messagePost.message = message;,
            //messagePost.description = "my description";

            var result = facebookClient.Post("/[user id]/feed", messagePost);
        }
        catch (FacebookOAuthException ex)
        {
             //handle something
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             //handle something else
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Hi Justin. Thanks for this, I was wondering if you could help. I am trying to write a job for Quartz.net that posts to a Page feed (of which I am an administrator) on a daily basis. It seems like this should be possible, but I'm getting a "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action" OAuth exception. I imagine it's because fo the settings in the Facebook app itself.

Any ideas how these need to be set? All very confusing. FB apps don't really seem built for this kind of automation.

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: EDIT: Some confusing stuff. See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/ - then go here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET and add your [userid]/accounts to the GET url, and click Get Access Token and enable the manage_pages. Convoluted, but I guess for good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer over here:
[how to post to facebook page wall from .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307606/how-to-post-to-facebook-page-wall-from-net/41042106#41042106#answer-41042106)

Check full example:
http://klaatuveratanecto.com/posting-on-facebook-wall-feed-with-c-and-asp-net-mvc-5/