# How to do a post in facebook on my page fan wall with c# and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tryed since 3 days how i create a post my fan page wall with c#, and i note 2 things :
- Facebook provides not updated documentation with no complete and poor example (api changes often)
- Facebook often changes his api and lots of post are obselete.
Is somebody can correct my code or provide me the complete good code ?

This is my code :

```
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["code"]))
            {
                Response.Redirect("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=157873644371673&redirect_uri=http://localhost:2551/Default.aspx&scope=publish_stream,manage_pages,offline_access&display=popup");
            }
            else
            {

    FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient();
                    dynamic result1 = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
                    {
                        client_id = "MY_APP_ID",
                        client_secret = "MY_SECRET_ID",
                        grant_type = "client_credentials",
                        redirect_uri = "www.mysite.com"
                    });

                    fb.AppId = "MY_APP_ID";
                    fb.AppSecret = "MY_SECRET_ID";
                    fb.AccessToken = result1.access_token;

                     dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
                    parameters.message = "Check out this funny article";
                    parameters.link = "http://www.example.com/article.html";
                    parameters.picture = "http://www.example.com/article-thumbnail.jpg";
                    parameters.name = "Article Title";
                    parameters.caption = "Caption for the link";
                    parameters.description = "Longer description of the link";
                    parameters.req_perms = "manages_pages";
                    parameters.scope = "manages_pages";

                    parameters.actions = new
                    {
                        name = "View on Zombo",
                        link = "www.zombo.com",
                    };
                    parameters.privacy = new
                    {
                        value = "ALL_FRIENDS",
                    };

                    try
                    {
                        var result = fb.Post("/" + "MY_FACEBOOK_FAN_PAGE_ID" + "/feed", parameters);
                    }
                    catch (FacebookOAuthException ex)
                    {
                        //handle something
                        Response.Write(ex.Message);
                    }
}
```

Comment: what erro are you getting

Comment: (OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307606/how-to-post-to-facebook-page-wall-from-net/41042106#41042106#answer-41042106

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope this post will be helpfull for lots of people, i try to be simple and clear :

1-Create your facebook developper account, and to test your code in your computern (`localhost`), set your localhost adress in the field "website authentication with facebook authentication".
For me it will be `http://localhost:2551/Default.aspx` for example because i test in the Defaut.aspx of my wweb application.
You 'll change this adress when you'll deploy on your website (for me i ll change with http://www.mywebsiteurl.com/Default.aspx just before deploy the code on my website).

2- With your facebook user account, create your fan page.

3-When you created your fan page , go to your fan page see the URL to obtain your PAGE_ID
For example mine is http://www.facebook.com/pages/toto/446533181408238?ref=ts&fref=ts
so my PAGE_ID is 446533181408238

3- It's almost finished, just a little explanation : because i created the fan page , i m administrator of the fan page and i must ask the authoraization to facebook to post since my developper account so i must get the autorisation for 2 actions : publish_stream and manage_pages.

Let's go for coding :

```
  private void Do()
        {
            string app_id = "157873644371675";
            string app_secret = "c27a10c347af4280720fa3d76c9ae08c";
            string scope = "publish_stream,manage_pages";

            if (Request["code"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect(string.Format(
                    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
                    app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));
            }
            else
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}",
                    app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);

                HttpWebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

                using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                    string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                    {
                        //meh.aspx?token1=steve&token2=jake&...
                        tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                            token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
                    }
                }

                string access_token = tokens["access_token"];

                var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);

                dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
                parameters.message = "Check out this funny article";
                parameters.link = "http://www.natiska.com/article.html";
                parameters.picture = "http://www.natiska.com/dav.png";
                parameters.name = "Article Title";
                parameters.caption = "Caption for the link";

                //446533181408238 is my fan page
                client.Post("/446533181408238/feed", parameters);

            }
              }
```

Comment: it didn't work as admin posting and it displayed in "Recent Posts by Others on my page name" with my name as poster!!

Answer (score 0):

There are some things wrong with the parameters you pass with your Graph API request.

1. You don't ask for the permissions efficiently:

   - the `req_perms` parameter is deprecated and has been replaced by `scope`,
   - the permissions are passed with the login link and not with the Graph API request at all!
2. The `action` field requires an **array** whereas the `privacy` field requires a **JSON**.

How an array looks like: `"actions": {'value': 'CUSTOM', 'allow': '{friend-list-id}'}`.

How a JSON looks like:

```
"privacy": [   
    {
      "name": "Comment", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/1234567890/posts/09876543210987654321"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Like", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/1234567890/posts/09876543210987654321"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using the following code to post image to my Facebook page wall

```
 string app_id = "*************";
string app_secret = "*************";
string scope = "publish_actions,manage_pages";
string accessToken = GetAccessToken(FacebookAppId, FacebookAppSecret);
            if (Request["code"] == null)
            {
Response.Redirect(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));
            }
            else
            {
                FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient();
                dynamic result1 = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
                {
                    client_id = "******",
                    client_secret = "*************",
                    grant_type = "publish_actions,manage_pages",
                    redirect_uri = "*************"
                });

                fb.AppId = "MY_APP_ID";
                fb.AppSecret = "MY_SECRET_ID";
                fb.AccessToken = result1.access_token;
// to make new object
                dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
                parameters.message = "Check out this funny article";
                parameters.link = "*************";
                parameters.picture = "*************";
                parameters.name = "*************";
                parameters.caption = "*************";
                parameters.description = "*************";
                parameters.req_perms = "*************";
                parameters.scope = "*************";

                parameters.actions = new
                {
                    name = "*************",
                    link = "*************",
                };
                parameters.privacy = new
                {
                    value = "*************",
                };

                try
                {
                    var result = fb.Post("/" + "*************" + "/feed", parameters);
                }
```