# how to post on directly at facebook page using C# not at visitor post?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

i refereed this post 
[how to post to facebook page wall from .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307606/how-to-post-to-facebook-page-wall-from-net) but it will work on facebook page to post as visitor post.
and i want to post of page timeline not at visitor post and i am admin of this page and app.
please give solution for it .

here in my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Facebook;
using System.Dynamic;

public partial class facebook : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        authontication();
    }
    private void authontication()
    {
        string app_id = "**********************";
        string app_secret = "###################################";


        string scope = "publish_actions,manage_pages";

        if (Request["code"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect(string.Format(
                "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
                app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));
        }
        else
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}",
            app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);

            HttpWebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();

                foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                {
                    //meh.aspx?token1=steve&token2=jake&...
                    tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                        token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
                }
            }
            string access_token = tokens["access_token"];
            var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);

            //dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            string name = "sudhanshu";

            name += " new data";

            client.Post("/1168908853153698/feed", new { message = "My first appProduct "+name+" ." });



        }

    }

}
```

Comment: use a page token, not a user token.

Comment: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: i am already using page token.

Comment: i don´t see that anywhere in your code, looks like you are only using a user token. check out my answer.

Comment: sorry sir,but i cant understand what you wants to say

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Page Token, not a User Token. Make sure it really is a Page Token by debugging it: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Also, `publish_actions` is the wrong permission to post as Page, you need to use `publish_pages`.

Additional information:

- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/page/feed#publish

Comment: i used publish_pages method but still its posting on visitor post

Comment: then you are not using a page token. make sure you know the difference between user and page token and check out the links.

Comment: Thanks For Helping ME Now I can able to Posting ON Facebook Page Directly .

Comment: sir But need one more help How to get Page access Token Dynamically??

Comment: what means "dynamically"? jsut use an extended page token.

Comment: Means actually i copy page access token from Facebook graph API and directly paste in my code.

Comment: string newtoken = "EAAWnl6jSbt4BAAYfHTxZClMOZCzBxI8KxyvIbguX7QpKAQs6IoSlQBZCS7qmO8vSKZBRmtlZBGyWP2ADjG48dLDUBZCgZAPbbb3hu7rTf3EB161mg9U55tkD29WZATraTp5ETmSlRZBEZB1mjyVb04TmuwfKlWA3iWxqOHu4yuk2ct9wZDZD";
            var client = new FacebookClient(newtoken);
            
            client.Post("/1168908853153698/feed", new { message = "My first appProduct  ." });

Comment: tokens need to be kept secret. i hope that´s not a valid one...still not sure what the question is, to be honest.

Comment: just read through all the links in my answer. create an "extended page token", it is valid forever. there is no need to programmatically create a page token.

Comment: IN short how to get Page access token at run time ,like we get user access token at run time

Comment: that is explained in detail in the links in my answer, just read all the text in those articles

Comment: i already reads this answer at link but not getting page access token after debug i get only user access token

Comment: the api call is /me/accounts. just go through the links again, there is not really anything else to say, i could only quote from them.