# Post to Facebook Page c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am struggling to post to a Facebook page (not personal page, but what was a fan page) from an ASP.Net web page.

I am using FacebookSDK.

I have used the code suggested here : [Simplest way to post to a facebook fan page's wall with C#!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878463/simplest-way-to-post-to-a-facebook-fan-pages-wall-with-c)

```
    class Program
     {
private const string FacebookApiId = "apiId";
private const string FacebookApiSecret = "secret";

private const string AuthenticationUrlFormat =
    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=manage_pages,offline_access,publish_stream";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string accessToken = GetAccessToken(FacebookApiId, FacebookApiSecret);

    PostMessage(accessToken, "My message");
}

static string GetAccessToken(string apiId, string apiSecret)
{
    string accessToken = string.Empty;
    string url = string.Format(AuthenticationUrlFormat, apiId, apiSecret);

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

        NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(responseString);

        accessToken = query["access_token"];
    }

    if (accessToken.Trim().Length == 0)
        throw new Exception("There is no Access Token");

    return accessToken;
}

static void PostMessage(string accessToken, string message)
{
    try
    {
        FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

        dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
        messagePost.access_token = accessToken;
        //messagePost.picture = "[A_PICTURE]";
        //messagePost.link = "[SOME_LINK]";
        //messagePost.name = "[SOME_NAME]";
        //messagePost.caption = "my caption"; 
        messagePost.message = message;,
        //messagePost.description = "my description";

        var result = facebookClient.Post("/[user id]/feed", messagePost);
    }
    catch (FacebookOAuthException ex)
    {
         //handle something
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         //handle something else
    }

}
```

}

The access token is returned, but I cannot post - {"(OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"}

I have looked up this error and changed the scope permissions to : scope=publish_actions,manage_pages,status_update

I have then read about you need to submit your application for review. I am not ready for that yet. So I tried as a Test App, but this has the same error returned.

It will only ever be the page admin who will post to the page. I am confused as to where the error is - with my code, with my app or because it is not submitted.

Does the app need to be submitted if only the page owner will post? What else could I be missing.

Many thanks